# Android Wear hide "Debugging over bluetooth" card

Tags: android, adb, wear-os

I was wondering if there is any way to hide the card "Debugging over bluetooth" when such activity is in progress. It's just not the best one to take screenshots with, and I don't seem to be able to dismiss it.

I *do* want to show a sample card in preview, but just not that one, so swiping it down to temporarily hide it is not an option.

I already tried blacklisting in Android Wear app several system-like notifications.

My wear device is a Moto 360, so bluetooth is the way to debug it.

Screenshot for reference:

[image: Android wear screenshot]

(Somehow, even if your device is round, screenshots through adb look square)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible to remove it. The only way is to stop debugging.
By the way, you can take screenshots with the Android Wear app without any need to debug.

Comment: Thanks, I completely missed that one feature of the Android Wear app.

Comment: How about screen recording? That is possible only via adb right?

Comment: Yes, and you will have to do some conversion: http://www.tinmith.net/wayne/blog/2014/08/android-wear-screenrecord.htm